# How to setup the yaml files for a modified map?

Tags: ros, nav2d-exploration, nav2d, nav2d-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
I'm using Nav2d where the part of simulator is replaced with my own physical robot. The map in simulator has larger dimension size than my map which is only 5x3 meters. Since the map size is changed then I understand that **costmap.yaml,  operator.yaml and navigator.yaml** has to be changed, where I have set them to :

**costmap.yalm**

```
global_frame: odom
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 10.0
publish_frequency: 2.0
publish_voxel_map: true
static_map: false
rolling_window: true
width: 6.0
height: 6.0
resolution: 0.05
map_type: costmap
track_unknown_space: true
transform_tolerance: 0.3
obstacle_range: 2.0
min_obstacle_height: 0.0
max_obstacle_height: 2.0
raytrace_range: 4.5
robot_radius: 0.4
inflation_radius: 0.75
cost_scaling_factor: 2.0
lethal_cost_threshold: 100
observation_sources: scan
scan: {data_type: LaserScan, expected_update_rate: 0.6,
  observation_persistence: 0.0, marking: true, clearing: true, max_obstacle_height: 0.4, min_obstacle_height: 0.08}
```

**operator.yaml**

```
max_velocity: 0.2
publish_route: true
max_free_space: 2.0
safety_decay: 0.50
distance_weight: 1
safety_weight: 2
conformance_weight: 1 
continue_weight: 0
```

**navigator.yaml**

```
map_inflation_radius: 1.0
robot_radius: 0.5
navigation_goal_distance: 0.10
navigation_goal_angle: 1.0
navigation_homing_distance: 0.30
exploration_goal_distance: 1.0
min_target_area_size: 1.0
visualize_frontiers: true
```

I understand the parameters in navigator when I change them, and it make good since but the reaction of robot is randomly each time when I change parameters in costmap and operator.

[image: image description]

My question is, am I hitting some limitations in these two files since robot stops after 20 cm moving or just make a turn ?
Is there other files I also must change when map size is changed ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234582/how-to-setup-the-yaml-files-for-a-modified-map?/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There shouldn't be a need to change any of these parameters just because you use a different map. The operators costmap is independent from the global map.

I assume you are using a static map together with the localizer. In that case note that you can't use path planning before the particle filter has converged to the robot's position, which it hasn't yet in your picture.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-05-18**:
I use localizer and static map. How can I decide to use particle filter first and then path planner if it is possible !?

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-05-18**:
I understand it in this way that first a desired goal is defined in map(by using 2D Nav Goal), then a shortest path is created and after that particle filter starts converge robot's position!

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-05-19**:
No, the path planner can't do any planning until it knows where the robot is. There is a service "Localize", that moves the robot straight until it gets a pose. See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d_navigator) for the action interface. You might need to start the localize_client to use the service.

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-05-19**:
When I click in map for desired goal it first find a path (pink line) very fast before robot make any moves. I haven't studiet Navigator code in detail but I only knew that it uses Dijkstra algorithm.

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-05-19**:
...and my question is how can path be created immediately first? But you mentioned service "Localize" take action first where it moves robot straight until it gets a position and then path is created!